# Declaring a char as " ' "

Tags: c++, char

I'm working on a syntaxcheck program for a school project.

It's supposed to read through a .c or .cc file and determine if the file's syntax is correct.
That means that comment sections and other exceptions needs to be handled by some kind of state handling.

My question is how you declare a `char` as ' ' '?

```
int lib::read_state(char a, char b) {

char c;

switch(a) {

    case '/':
        if(combine_chars(a,b) == "/*") {
            return BLOCKCOMMENT;
        }
        else if(combine_chars(a,b) == "//") {
            return ROWCOMMENT;
        }
        else 
            return CODE;

    case '"':
        return STRING;

    default: 

        return CHARACTER;
}

}
```

Combine chars is a function that turns two chars into a string and then compares them and the return values are simple `enums`.

Here is the code, as you can see i need another case that handles char declaration.
I tried putting case ''' , but that didn't work, also "'" did not work either.

Im open for suggestions here if there is any way.

Thanks !

Comment: This is incredibly basic. Which C++ book are you using?

Comment: I hope your function `combine_char` returns a `std::string` and not a pointer, otherwise you either have undefined behavior or a memory leak, as well as the comparison not working.

Comment: If `combine_chars` does what I think it does, you can replace it with `std::string{a, b}`. As a bonus, it works with any number of characters.

Comment: @chris: In this case, of course, you'd just `if (b == '*')` in the first place...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, Indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By "[escaping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character)" it with a backslash:

```
'\''
```

Comment: You could also cast from the ascii value `char(39)`

Comment: @Pat, Sure, if you're assuming ASCII is in use and want to need a comment explaining what 39 is.

Comment: @chris or you could do something readable like `#define ASCII_SINGLE_QUOTE 39`  and then `char(ASCII_SINGLE_QUOTE)`  Or the more C++ like `const char ASCII_SINGLE_QUOTE(39);`

Comment: Or you could write `'\''`

Answer (score 0):

You just have to escape it with a \

```
char single_quote='\'';
```